# Appending multiple list index into a single list then using join to print them

Tags: python

Hello i have this script This script should take 2 files split them into 2 lists after that add them up together in one list and write their content in one file but the problem is that one of the file might have a list length on 1+ index some of them are 5 so of them are 10 so i need w.e is the length of the first and second list add them to a single list and write them in a single file without the [] and the ' between the data thank you here the script

```
import re
f = open('Firsttext.txt', 'r')
d = open('second.txt', 'r')
w = open('combination.txt','w')
s=""
filtred=[]
Mlines=f.readlines()
Wlines=d.readlines()
for line in Wlines:
    Wspl=line.split()
    for line2 in Mlines:
        Mspl=line2.split()
        if ((Mspl[0]).lower()==(Wspl[0])):
            Wspl.append(Mspl[1])
            print (Wspl)
            s="\t".join(Wspl)+"\n"
            if s not in filtred:
                filtred.append(s)
                break
for x in filtred:
    w.write(x)
f.close()
d.close()
w.close()
```

Comment: Could you post an example of both files?

Comment: nah can't :/ files first file contain mac ip number device

Comment: second file contain Mac name(could be one or w.e names)

Comment: You can add a representation of it. It doesn't have to be the exact details :)

Comment: first file: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 000xxxxxx Android-2.10.750
second file: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  xxxx xx xx xxx xxx xxxxx

Comment: And sorry for the questions, but what is your expected output? I can't seem to understand you. Sorry

Comment: first file: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 000xxxxxx Android-2.10.750 
second file: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx xxxx xx xx xxx xxx xxxxx
combination: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 000xxxxxx Android-2.10.750 xxxx xx xx xxx xxx xxxxx (without the mac address)

Comment: I meant what should appear in the `combination.txt`

Comment: the 2 lists combined together Mac IP Number Device Name Name Name ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the content of each file first, then join them.

```
from itertools import izip
with open('file1.txt') as f1:
    lines1 = f1.readlines()

with open('file2.txt') as f2:
    lines2 = f2.readlines()

with open('combinations.txt', 'w+') as f3:
    for i, j in izip(lines1, lines2):
        f3.write(i + ' ' + j.split(None, 1)[-1]))
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Data/Test2.py", line 11, in <module>
    f3.write(line)
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

Comment: @user2597549 Sorry! Fixing

Comment: like i had 900KB of data its now 43KB

Comment: @user2597549 Try now. I'm not an expert in performance, sorry about that

Comment: @user2597549 Ah, you must be using python 3. Just ignore `from itertools import izip`, and remove the `i` from `izip()` in the second last line :)

Comment: same its still eating the data :(

Comment: @user2597549 Sorry then, I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: sorry for wasting your time

Comment: @user2597549 Nah, it's fine :). I enjoy answering questions and I do it to learn more myself :)

Comment: yeah thanks i got the solution tho :D but i'm having a problem in data loss :(

Comment: Note that `zip` terminates iteration when the *shorter* iterable terminates. If you have files with different number of lines(say `n < m`) then only `n` lines are processed. To avoid this you should use `itertools.zip_longest`. Something like `with open('file1') as f1, open('file2') as f2, open('output', 'w') as out: for a, b in zip_longest(f1, f2, fillvalue=''): out.write('{}\t{}'.format(a, b))` Note that this avoid reading the whole files into memory. [depending on your requirements the added `\t` may or may not be a problem]

Comment: @user2597549 Does Bakuriu's post above help?